# Using custom classes with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm developing a Sinatra application. To simplify the structure for an easier future support I added a few custom classes, located in separate files. What I'm trying to do is to make them use existing helpers and sinatra's own functionality (models, sessions, etc) without repeating the code.

For example, I have a helper **to_html**(text) and I'd like to use it both inside sinatra routes and in my own classes, which are also to be used inside routes.

My sinatra app is written in *classic* style (if it matters for your suggestion).

Is it possible?

Comment: I guess you just need to put `require 'my_class'` after `require 'sinatra'` in the main file which you use to run the server.

Comment: No, it doesn't see helper methods:
    NameError - undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Comment: Please provide a minimal code sample that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a helpers directory in the root of the project, you could do something like this from inside your app file you use to run the server.

```
%w(helpers).each { |p| Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), p, "*.rb")].each { |file| require file } }
```

You will need to include your routes below this for it to work. To make this even cleaner, you can also have a routes/controllers directory. Simply add 'routes' to that array as such:

```
%w(helpers routes).each { |p| Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), p, "*.rb")].each { |file| require file } }
```

This will require all of your helpers THEN your routes.